# Updated app, still, old version is downloaded from the App Store

Tags: app-store, submit

Something strange happened to me. I updated my app and it was approved. When I downloaded it I was shocked to see that it was the old app. Not the updated one. The improvements were countless.. so I could tell the difference between the old app and the update done. I also didn't drink anything. How could this happen? Have you encounter this before?

Comment: +1 for clarifying that you hadn't drunk anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may take up to a few hours for AppStore to display a newly approved app.

Comment: I know that. But it appears as the updated one. With the 'Update' button on the right. So it seems kind of available for download. But the old version is what I get.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally upload the binary of the old version?

Comment: Actualy when I 'Get Info' of the ipa in iTunes I see 1.1. The previous version. How was possible for xcode to send the older version? Since I archived and sent the last one from the list in the Organizer? Even so, isn't it strange that I could upload an app with a version number not the same as stated in iTunes Connect?

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered this bug. I believe it is App Store bug.

This is a workaround solution to the bug. To download the real/correct version, go to App Store > Updates tab > select your app and update.

Answer (score 2):

I also just encountered this bug.

Just received the standard app status "ready for sale" approval notice from Apple about an hour and a half ago.  I didn't have the app on my iPhone 4, went to the app store to download the new version, and received the old version instead.  All the meta-data was updated with the new release information.

As samwize mentions in the above post, the new version was available by going to App Store > Updates tab > select app and update.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this very same thing and was pulling my hair out until just now. It seems like the meta-data is updated before the binary is in place. When the binary is in place (about 2 hours after the meta data in my case) you will get the "Update"-button and get notified that there is a new version to download.

You will get the update notification even if you just downloaded the old version with the new meta data. My worry was that if new users downloaded the app in the time between new meta data and new binary they would not get the update but it seems like thats not a problem luckily.